# Eclipse with Android ADK emulator preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Running Win7 with root user dir reflected to d:\ not c:.  Preferences and options ARE set to d:\, but I get this response after following the Eclipse new-user Hello, World Exercise:

```
[2011-08-01 22:15:32 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------  
 Android Launch!  
 adb is running normally.  
 Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch  
 Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'my_1st_AVD' is not available. Launching new emulator.  
 Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_1st_AVD'  
[2011-08-01 22:15:32 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\Chuck\.android/avd/my_1st_AVD.ini"
```

I found the file in d:, and yes, my workspace is added to my Documents Library.

Ideas?

Comment: Just so you know, people do not CC or email others the answers the questions posed on this site. It's answered directly here and you must come back to this site to see the answer. Just a heads up.

Comment: Also, this may seem stupid, but double check where your workspace is set to.

Comment: Thanks - the preferences are set correctly.  Turned out to be a secondary fail due to Eclipse's inability to read folders other than 8.3 format.  SOLUTION: Deleted old workspace, ran Eclipse with "-clean" command line option, and changed the SDK folder in Window > Preferences to "Progra~2" (which is PF(86) on my machine). I then loaded a 2.2 iOS emulator, rather than 3.2.  Worked fine after that!

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse: try going to Window > Preferences > Android and change your SDK location to wherever your "android-sdk" folder is.

Comment: This DID turn out to be the problem.  Apparently Eclipse balks at spaces in folder names.  Changing "Program Files (86)" to "Progra~2" worked.  The clue, on repeated running, was an error message not previously presented that the Files parameter was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found an answer on google code.
In android project, issue 19084.
Just as comment 14 said,
"As a work-around, you can define the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to the directory containing your .android directory. The emulator and SDK Manager will pick it up properly."

I followed it and problem solved. You may give it a try. Good luck.